# PHP and GETTEXT no translation for fr_FR

Tags: php, gettext, language-translation

On my home computer(win7 ultimate), i made a web site in french and in english with gettext AND all works perfectly,

Now I want to put it online, so i transfer it on my server but only english translation works... no french translation.... It's been 1 week i'm trying to fix it but with no result.

So, i find an artile ... "gettext will only support the installed locales." In linux, with this command "locale -a" I can see all locales installed and if "fr_FR" is not instralled, it's normal that there is no translation in french, so with another command, i can install it.

**But my server is with Windows Web 2008 r2, so this command "locale -a" doesn't work.**

I'm asking your help to help me to figure it out for the language(locale) fr_FR works..?
How can i check if the language(locale) fr_FR is installed? and if not, how can i install it?
Thanks a lot for your help... If i didn't post in good Category, please let me know and i will post it again in an other category.

Answer (score 0):

It should be within the control panel, then in the keyboards installed. I see no other alternative for locale installations...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I check keyboard install, i have english US and english canada multilingual.... the same i have on my own computer and on my own computer gettext work perfectly.

Man i'm really lost now....   what my computer has that my server don't have......
other idea?

Comment: try adding a french keyboard maybe?

Comment: "Note:

On Windows, setlocale(LC_ALL, '') sets the locale names from the system's regional/language settings (accessible via Control Panel). " from http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows uses different [language strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28vs.71%29.aspx). Try "french" instead of "fr_FR".

Comment: yes i already check it and i just try it again.... it doesn't work..
The fact is on computer(for test) GETTEXT works perfectly and i use en_US and fr_FR, and my test computer is Windows 7 Ultimate.... but it dosn't work on my server with Windows Web 2008 r2... Other idea?